getTransaction method always returns null
No matter what transaction signature I give it, this method will always return me null. Here is an example code:
const axios = require('axios');

async function getTransaction() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('https://api.devnet.solana.com', {
      jsonrpc: '2.0',
      id: 1,
      method: 'getTransaction',
      params: [
        '8crW2M8mwCTLmbUbnbthi8KYyvN9iQd2a1XnTQvs9Zu4cTrFAaprU6fic66GLCVoovp5BX8e6cCJ38cYWhr7vg1',
        'jsonParsed'
      ]
    }, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });

    console.log(response.data); // Assuming you want to log the response data
    return response.data; // Return the response data if needed
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    throw error; // Rethrow the error if needed
  }
}

// Call the function
getTransaction();

And the answer always is
{jsonrpc: '2.0', result: null, id: 1}

I have the latest @solana.js --> @solana/web3.js@1.91.7. The problem persists even if I use curl.
If someone want's to replicate it, just visit https://reqbin.com/curl and use the example from the getTransaction method on Solana https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction#code-sample

The devnet node you're using doesn't have all history, and the transactions you're querying are likely from before its cutoff.
If we search for your transaction signature in Explorer, we get a clue: "Note: Transactions processed before block 116113408 are not available at this time"
It's the same for the one in the docs
Here's an example on reqbin that should work: https://reqbin.com/c-z4x3miat
Or with curl:
curl https://api.devnet.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getTransaction",
    "params": [
      "4ZDv6N9fCYxJi3gTvvHNEEesU9mHoQuYFPyYchHLj3x7VYNMUWHDdPq6gMHBHrQMr1j6Xascm7ZVbwbsxrfffUo2",
      "json"
    ]
  }
'


oh my god, I am dumb. I haven't seen that I am trying to access the devnet and not the mainnet..
